# Distribute table data to another table using SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2012

Help on how to distribute  **Default Table** into **Transaction Table** using SQL Server Query if month is not existing on the other side? Please refer on the sample tables below

Default Table

| Month | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 0 |
| Feb | 0 |
| Mar | 0 |
| Apr | 0 |
| May | 0 |

Transaction Table

| Month | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 10 |
| Feb | 0 |
| Apr | 20 |

I want to achieve this below results.

| Month | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 10 |
| Feb | 0 |
| Mar | 0 |
| Apr | 20 |
| May | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```sql
INSERT INTO Transaction (Month, Sales)
SELECT c.Month, d.Sales
FROM [Default] d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Transaction t
    WHERE t.Month = d.Month)
```